# How to link a front-end button to a Node event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, steam, steam-web-api

So I've made a node server that allows me to sign-in with steam and redirect back to the site. My question is: is there a way that I can place the sign-in/sign-out buttons in an AngularJS front end and use the server as a proxy server that handles the steam Auth process? Do I just need to place an event listener and a click event to kick off the Auth process?

My front end is localhost:8080 
My back end is localhost:4000

Also, once I've received the user's steam ID, how would I make that available to the front end? Would I need to make a small API?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would create a small api that the front end calls on your server. It also allows you to split the two onto different servers in the future if it needs to scale up more.

Comment: Would it allow me to use the button in the front end that starts the steam auth process?

Comment: Yes, create a button that calls a function on the front end that makes the call to your backend node api. I am not entirely familiar with the steam auth process but it may also be the case where you can start that process from the front end button instead.